# Flexbox and vertical align not working in IE Edge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm trying to **align columns vertically** inside a row in Bootstrap `3.3.7 using flexbox`. The row must be have a min-height of `62px`.

I have **three** columns; one column, (`.title`), is always containing some text, the two others may be `hidden or empty` at times. No matter what, they should always be aligned vertically in the row.

**I have this html**:

```css
.titlebar {
  border: 1px solid red;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  min-height: 62px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.titlebar .title {
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 21px;
}
.titlebar .byline {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row titlebar">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-3 title">Title</div>
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-3 byline"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 visible-xs-block titlebar-gradient"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It's working in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE Edge.
[See Bootply here](http://www.bootply.com/TcoMPl7vW5). What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it seems that IE 10-11 doesn't work with min-height: https://philipwalton.com/articles/normalizing-cross-browser-flexbox-bugs/

Changing min-height to height solves the issue.

Comment: Same thing is happening in Edge still. You saved me a lot of time and headache at my job with this comment.